# Problem with Rails ERb rendering?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

A very simple HTML in my .erb file:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="xyz">Click</a>
```

But when browsing this code in the browser, I get the link which text is:

```
Click (javascript:void(0)).
```

Could you please help me explain why it is? Thanks much for your help.

My development environment:
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.4

Comment: First, there is no ruby in this, only HTML.  Second, that link should produce a link with only the word "Click" in it in all browsers.  Maybe your problem is unclear.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happening when I had deployed my Rails application and browser was thinking that I'm in a "Print" mode. It'll append a URL after each link so that you don;t have to guess what link is after you print it on paper.

In my case it was happening with Blueprint CSS framework. See if you can fix it by disabling any CSS for "print"

Comment: I'm glad I helped. I wasted 2 hours on this ;-) You also can mark my answer as "answered" so that others can easily identify this as a solution.