# ERB code not rendering in view. Development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

The views I have created previously are all working fine. I generated a model and controller for subscriptions and have the corresponding views linked to my home page. No error is thrown, but my erb code isn't being rendered to my browser. I can add html (i.e. 'hello world' wrapped in div's).

I've tried the following.

1. Stripped the surrounding html code and just tried rails helper methods wrapped in erb.
2. Deleted and re-generated both Subscription model and subscriptions controller/views
3. Checked my routes.rb file for subscription-related issues
4. Looked at both of these related questions from SO to no avail. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457454/problem-with-rails-erb-rendering)
   [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286423/erb-files-not-rendered)

Here is a look at my code and output from webrick:

[webrick output](https://gist.github.com/sirramongabriel/6297334)

```
# subscriptions/index.html.erb

<% form_for(@subscription) do |f| %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="widget widget-table">
        <div class="widget-header">
          <h3>
            <i class="icon-"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Pay with Credit Card
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-content">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <% if @subscription.stripe_card_token.present? %>
                    Credit card has been provided.
                  <% else %>
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
                      <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
                      <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
                      <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
                      <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <% end %>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                  <div id="stripe_error">
                    <noscript><!--Error here--></noscript>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div><!-- END CLASS widget-content -->
      </div><!-- END CLASS widget widget-table -->
    </div><!-- END CLASS span12 -->
  </div><!-- END CLASS row-fluid -->
</div><!-- END CLASS container -->
<% end %>

# routes.rb

Whizcharts::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :subscriptions, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  # START devise routes
  devise_for :admins, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }# , path_names: { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout" }

  mount Deviseadmin::Engine, at: "/deviseadmin"

  devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout" }
  ## END devise routes

  # START mailer
    # match 'admins/show', to: "admins#show"
  ## END mailer

  # START static_pages routes
  root to: "static_pages#home"
  match "static_pages/about", to: "static_pages#about", as: :about
  match "static_pages/pricing", to: "static_pages#pricing", as: :pricing
  match "static_pages/contact", to: "static_pages#contact", as: :contact
  ## END static_pages routes

  # START deployments routes
  match "deployments/deployment_print", to: "residents#deployment_print", as: :print



# subscriptions_controller.rb

# Note: Subscription.new is in the index method temporarily to demonstrate this issue

class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subscription = Subscription.new
    @subscriptions = Subscription.all
  end

  def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end
end

# subscription.rb

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin, dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :plan_id

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
end


# admin.rb

# Note: Included to demonstrate the association between the Admin and Subscription models

class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :fac_name,    :fac_address, :fac_city, :fac_state, :fac_zip, :lic_num, :owner_fname, :owner_lname, :fac_phone1,:fac_phone2, :fac_phone3, :fac_phone4, :fac_phone5, :fac_email1, :fac_email2, :fac_email3, :fac_email4, :fac_email5, :initials

  has_many :residents
  has_many :fund_record_form2s, through: :residents
  has_many :deployments
  has_many :subscriptions

  def full_name
    "#{owner_fname} #{owner_lname}"
  end
end
```

I am running rails 3.2.14

If I forgot something, I will put it up promptly after your notification.

Comment: You are missing the equal(`=`) sign. It should be `<%= form_for(@subscription) do |f| %>`

Comment: Thanks Neo! Overlooked typo. I appreciate the point out.

Comment: I have added it as an answer, could you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the equal(`=`) sign.

It should be `<%= form_for(@subscription) do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the equal sign before the form_for helper.

```
<%= form_for %>
```

You need the equal sign, otherwise the ERB tags are not put on the template.